Unresolved External Symbol in minizip.lib
When linking the minizip.lib library, the linker throws an error indicating that it cannot resolve an external symbol _ONcrc32 referenced in the function _mz_crypt_crc32_update.(I am trying to compile Minizip 4.0.7 for Windows platform and after compilation I am using libminizip.lib in my project but I am getting unresolved external symbol error for _ONcrc32)
I have linked zlib library but still this error is coming up.
Can you help me with this?
minizip.lib(mz_crypt.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ONcrc32 referenced in function _mz_crypt_crc32_update

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
